# How to implement the method (hex (hmac_sha1 (param, secretKey)) in Python

Tags: python, hash

Is there any way that we could implement the following hash mechanism in python?

1. Join all the http request query parameter alphabetically.
   param1=concatByAlphabetical(arg1+value1,arg2+value2,arg3+value3…)
   Note: The “value1” & “value2” & “value3” is the value before URLEncoding.
2. Concat appKey with param1
   param2=concat (urlPath, param1). 
   The urlPath is the highlighter in URL like this:
   https://gw.api.alibaba.com/api/xml/1/sy ... a_=xxx&a=b
   For example:
   If the “GET” request URL is 
   http://gw.api.alibaba.com/api/json/1/sy ... e/1?_data={a=1,b=2}&_aop_respon
   seFormat=xml.
   The param2 will be: json/1/system/currentTime/1_aop_responseFormatxml_data{a=1,b=2}
3. Using HMAC_SHA1 algorithm to make the signature.
   Signature=uppercase (hex (hmac_sha1 (param2, secretKey))

Comment: You will probably find the [hmac](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html) standard library module useful.